# Maximise probability of non-empty urns by addings balls.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization

I have K urns and in each of them i have already some white and some black balls (different number in each of the urns). I have an equal chance of picking any of the urns. I have in my hands X white balls and Y black balls. I would like to know how to distribute them in the urns so that i maximise the probability to get a white balls when i pick one urns and one balls in that urns.

I tested it out myself to find that adding white balls to the urns with the less balls give a quite good increase but it also seems to be not the best answer. I also got a K equations with K variable system, but i was wondering if there is a more basic solution behind this.

Comment: If you choose the urn on a uniform distribution (entirely randomly), then the probability of choosing a white ball is the average of the fraction of white balls in each urn. $$ P = \frac{1}{\sharp \text{Urns}}\sum_{u \in \text{Urns}} \frac{\sharp \text{White balls in } u}{\sharp \text{Balls in } u}$$ Now apply Jensen's inequality and pay attention to the case of the equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need every urn to start with some balls to avoid your probability being $\frac00$.

Let's suppose urn $i$ already has $b_i$ black balls and $w_i$ white balls and that you add the spare balls one-by-one.

Adding a white ball to urn $i$ increases the probability of winning by $\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{w_i+1}{b_i+w_i+1} - \frac{w_i}{b_i+w_i}\right)= \frac{b_i}{k(b_i+w_i+1)(b_i+w_i)}$ so put a spare white ball in the urn for which this calculation is highest (any of the urns for which it is the equal highest).

Similarly  adding a black ball to to urn $i$ reduces the probability of winning by $\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{w_i}{b_i+w_i} - \frac{w_i}{b_i+w_i+1}\right)= \frac{w_i}{k(b_i+w_i+1)(b_i+w_i)}$ so put a spare black ball in the urn for which this calculation is lowest (any of the urns for which it is the equal lowest).

Then move on to the next spare ball.

It gets a little more complicated if any of the urns start empty as you want to avoid your probability being $\frac00$ at the end, but essentially you want as many urns as possible to have $1$ white ball and $0$ black balls, and would be happy if all the black balls were in a single urn.